# The temple of tourists and tables

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

11 tourists are standing in an ancient temple (6x6 grid).
The temple contains 16 stone tables.
Each tourist is facing either north, south, west, or east and sees a different number of tables.
The numbers in the grid indicate where each tourist is standing and how many tables they see.
Each cell holds either a tourist, a table, or nothing (no overlaps).
A tourist can see anything in front of them at 45 degree angles. Tables and tourists do not block lines of sight.

For example, in this hypothetical temple (with 6 tables marked "T"), the tourist numbered "4" is facing north and can see 4 tables. Yellow squares are in their line of sight.

[image: EXAMPLE]

Here is the actual temple. Where are the 16 tables located?
[image: temple]

Text version:

```
Example:  
y y T 1 T y
T y T y y -
- 3 y y - -
- T 4 - - -
- - - T - -
- - - - - -

Puzzle:  
- - 2 - - 9
- - - 0 - -
7 5 - 3 - 10
- - - - 4 -
- 6 - 1 - -
- - 8 - - -
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is way I solved it; there may well be a shorter and/or more elegant solution.

> If 0 faces E then 2 must face W. Thus, among the sixteen still-empty squares in

> [image]

> there are fourteen with tables. Then 4 must be facing S, and 1 too. So among the eleven still-empty squares in

> [image]

> there are ten with tables. But then there's no direction 5 can face. So 0 doesn't face E, and must therefore face N. So we have

> [image]

> Now, 8 faces N, so there must be eight tables south of 8's line of sight, which means (because 1 can only see one of them) that we have

> [image]

> If 7 is facing E there's not enough room west of 7's line of sight for nine more tables, so 7 is facing S. Thus,

> [image]

> Now, 10 must be facing W, so

> [image]

> We need four more tables, so 5 can't be facing N, so 5 is facing E, and

> [image]

> And thus

> [image]

> Let's make sure all the numbers work:

> 0 faces N, 1 S, 2 E, 3 E, 4 S, 5 E, 6 N, 7 S, 8 N, 9 S, and 10 W: yep, it works.

Comment: This is great! I think my solution was a bit shorter so I'll write that up too

Answer (score 5):

The solution is

> T T 2 Y Y 9 
>  T T Y 0 Y T 
>  7 5 Y 3 Y 10 
>  T T Y Y 4 T 
>  T 6 T 1 T T 
>  T T 8 T Y T

Here is my approach:

> We start off with the puzzle
>  - - 2 - - 9 
> - - - 0 - - 
> 7 5 - 3 - 10 
> - - - - 4 - 
> - 6 - 1 - - 
> - - 8 - - -

> 7 must be S (E would not provide enough T for the grid). 
>  - - 2 - - 9 
> - - - 0 - - 
> 7 5 - 3 - 10 
> T T - - 4 - 
> T 6 T 1 - - 
> T T 8 T - -

> This forces 1S and 0N 
>  - - 2 Y Y 9 
> - - - 0 - - 
> 7 5 - 3 - 10 
> T T - - 4 - 
> T 6 T 1 - - 
> T T 8 T Y -

> If we consider 10W, there are 8 positions not seen by 10 and 6T not seen by 10. 2 positions have Y, so the rest must be T 
>  - - 2 Y Y 9 
> - - - 0 - T 
> 7 5 - 3 - 10 
> T T - - 4 T 
> T 6 T 1 T T 
> T T 8 T Y T

> 2E and 5E place the rest of the Y 
>  - - 2 Y Y 9 
> - - Y 0 Y T 
> 7 5 Y 3 Y 10 
> T T Y Y 4 T 
> T 6 T 1 T T 
> T T 8 T Y T

> Then we can fill in the rest of the T 
>  T T 2 Y Y 9 
>  T T Y 0 Y T 
> 7 5 Y 3 Y 10 
> T T Y Y 4 T 
> T 6 T 1 T T 
> T T 8 T Y T